Can I point CMake to use the (older) libc of a different rootfs?
I'm moving this here from the CMake Discourse. I’m trying to set up CMake to cross compile an application that will run on an old (Debian stretch ~2017) Linux system (functioning, but slow, so I'd prefer to compile my project on my WSL-Ubuntu-22.04-work-PC, and then copy the files on the target platform). I managed to write a toolchain file (below) and I can compile the project, but of course the libc picked is the one present on my system (which is way newer than the one present on the target). So I made a copy of the target root fs onto my machine, in /opt/box-root-fs. My idea is that by setting CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH and CMAKE_SYSROOT the compiler would have looked into that root fs, but apparently that’s not the case. If I try to print the compilation commands with VERBOSE=1 make I see something like:
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/opt/box-root-fs   -g -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/abertulli/two_lidars/main.cpp

so the --sysroot is correctly set, but then if I try to print with -v the precise include dirs, I find:
abertulli@SAN34400:~/two_lidars/build$ /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ --sysroot=/opt/box-root-fs   -g -std=gnu++14 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/abertulli/two_lidars/main.cpp -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
Target: arm-linux-gnueabihf
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-11/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++,m2 --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-11 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-libitm --disable-libquadmath --disable-libquadmath-support --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --enable-libphobos-checking=release --without-target-system-zlib --enable-multiarch --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-arch=armv7-a+fp --with-float=hard --with-mode=thumb --disable-werror --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf --program-prefix=arm-linux-gnueabihf- --includedir=/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf/include --with-build-config=bootstrap-lto-lean --enable-link-serialization=2
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-std=gnu++14' '-MD' '-MT' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o' '-MF' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o.d' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o' '-c' '-v' '-shared-libgcc'  '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-mthumb' '-mlibarch=armv7-a+fp' '-march=armv7-a+fp' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/cc1plus -quiet -v -imultilib . -imultiarch arm-linux-gnueabihf -isysroot /opt/box-root-fs -MD CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.d -MF CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o.d -MT CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o -D_GNU_SOURCE /home/abertulli/two_lidars/main.cpp -quiet -dumpdir CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/ -dumpbase main.cpp.cpp -dumpbase-ext .cpp -mfloat-abi=hard -mtls-dialect=gnu -mthumb -mlibarch=armv7-a+fp -march=armv7-a+fp -g -std=gnu++14 -version -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Wformat-security -o /tmp/ccC1Bx16.s
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
        compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/opt/box-root-fs/usr/local/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/include-fixed"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/11
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/11/arm-linux-gnueabihf/.
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include/c++/11/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/include
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/include
 /opt/box-root-fs/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabihf
 /opt/box-root-fs/usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C++14 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) version 11.4.0 (arm-linux-gnueabihf)
        compiled by GNU C version 11.4.0, GMP version 6.2.1, MPFR version 4.1.0, MPC version 1.2.1, isl version isl-0.24-GMP

GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: f8dab96d7e7b711d866ac6ec96f46fba
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-std=gnu++14' '-MD' '-MT' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o' '-MF' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o.d' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o' '-c' '-v' '-shared-libgcc'  '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-mthumb' '-mlibarch=armv7-a+fp' '-march=armv7-a+fp' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/'
 /usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/as -v -march=armv7-a -mfloat-abi=hard -meabi=5 -o CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o /tmp/ccC1Bx16.s
GNU assembler version 2.38 (arm-linux-gnueabihf) using BFD version (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/:/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/11/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/lib/:/opt/box-root-fs/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/opt/box-root-fs/lib/:/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/:/opt/box-root-fs/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-g' '-std=gnu++14' '-MD' '-MT' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o' '-MF' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o.d' '-o' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.o' '-c' '-v' '-shared-libgcc'  '-mfloat-abi=hard' '-mtls-dialect=gnu' '-mthumb' '-mlibarch=armv7-a+fp' '-march=armv7-a+fp' '-dumpdir' 'CMakeFiles/two_lidars.dir/main.cpp.'

so the search for include directories still uses the system ones, I think, and I presume the search for libraries does too. How can I make it search for the old libraries present in the copied fs? Thanks!

Project files:
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7)
PROJECT(two_lidars)

# Change as wished
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

###########
# toojpeg #
###########
add_library(toojpeg toojpeg/toojpeg.cpp)

target_include_directories(toojpeg PUBLIC ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)


################
# single lidar #
################

set(SINGLE_LIDAR_NAME single_lidar_listener)

set(single_lidar_files
  single_lidar.cpp
  sick_scan_xd_api_wrapper.c
)

add_executable(${SINGLE_LIDAR_NAME} ${single_lidar_files})

# needs toojpeg
target_link_libraries(${SINGLE_LIDAR_NAME} toojpeg)

# set(SINGLE_LIDAR_INCLUDE_DIRS ${INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# need sick
find_package(sick_scan_xd REQUIRED)
set(SINGLE_LIDAR_INCLUDE_DIRS ${SINGLE_LIDAR_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${SICK_SCAN_XD_INCLUDE_DIR})

include(CMakePrintHelpers)
cmake_print_variables(SICK_SCAN_XD_LIBRARIES SICK_SCAN_XD_INCLUDE_DIR)

target_include_directories(${SINGLE_LIDAR_NAME} PUBLIC ${SINGLE_LIDAR_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(${SINGLE_LIDAR_NAME} PUBLIC /usr/local/include)
target_link_libraries(${SINGLE_LIDAR_NAME} ${SICK_SCAN_XD_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${SINGLE_LIDAR_NAME} ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})

########
# main #
########

set(main_files
  main.cpp
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${main_files})

toolchain file TC-arm-linux-gnueabihf.cmake:
# the name of the target operating system
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)

# which compilers to use for C and C++
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

# where is the target environment located
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /opt/box-root-fs)
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /opt/box-root-fs)

# adjust the default behavior of the FIND_XXX() commands:
# search programs in the host environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)

# search headers and libraries in the target environment
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

I invoke the configuration with
mkdir -p ./build/ && cd build && cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../TC-arm-linux-gnueabihf.cmake ..

and then compile with make. The directory /opt/box-root-fs is a copy of the / of the target system

The problem is not about your CMake code, but is about the compiler itself. According to the output you provide, the compiler has been built with --with-sysroot=/ option. Here they suggest that with such configuration a directory / will be searched in any case.

BTW, it is quite useless to add to the variable CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH a value, which you have already assigned to CMAKE_SYSROOT.

thanks @Tsyvarev , I also just found the answer you linked. At this point, is there anything I can do to override this behaviour?

Probably, you need to built separate gcc which is suitable for cross-compiling. Or find the already built one. I am not expert in building gcc, so I cannot provide more details.

Did you try to set the compiler in your target machine's corresponding compiler?
It seems to be getting your machine's compiler:
/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
I think setting CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER and CMAKE_C_COMPILER in your toolchain file could do the trick.
Aside from that, you can also try using docker container in your machine and compile in it.

as you can see from the toolchain CMake script, I am setting those two variables, and they are producing correct ARM code, but they link by default against their own libc, which is not compatible with the one on the target system. As for a Docker container, I don't know hot to set up one for compiling, especially with a such old distro for which it is difficult to find images. Have you ever done this before? If so, can you please share some resources you followed?

Yes I saw that you set those variables but since it is located in your own root files, I thought that maybe giving the target machine's compiler would solve the problem. I mean the target machine's compiler would be in: /opt/box-root-fs/usr/bin/.
I did not do specific docker image for an old distro, I was just thinking another possible solution.

that would be a nice possibility, but the target PC has a different ISA (arm), so I'd need an emulator to run that compiler
